# Equivalence in Portmanteau's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I'm trying to understand the proof of one of the equivalences in Portmanteau's lemma. The equivalence (or implication rather, as that's what I'm trying to prove) is this:

> For any random vectors $X_n$ and $X$, the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) $P(X_n\leq x) \to P(X\leq x)$ for all continuity points of $x \mapsto P(X\leq x)$;
>
> (ii) $Ef(X_n)\to Ef(X)$ for all bounded, continuous functions $f$.

The proof I'm trying to understand is for showing that (i) implies (ii). It starts like this.

> First, we assume that the distribution function of $X$ is continuous.
>   Then for every rectangle $I$, condition (i) implies that $P(X_n\in
> > I)\to P(X\in I)$. We choose a (sufficiently large) compact rectangle
>   $I$ with $P(X \not\in I)<\epsilon$. A continuous function $f$ is
>   uniformly continuous on the compact set $I$, and there exists a
>   partition $I=\cup_j I_j$ into finitely many rectangles $I_j$ such that
>   $f$ varies at most $\epsilon$ on every $I_j$. We take a point $x_j$
>   from each $I_j$ and define $f_\epsilon=\sum_j f(x_j)1_{I_j}$. Then
>   $|f-f_\epsilon|<\epsilon$ on $I$.

At this point, my book says "*whence if $f$ takes its values in $[-1, 1]$*" which I'm uncertain how to interpret. In any case, this leads to the following:
$$
|Ef(X_n)-Ef_\epsilon(X_n)|\leq \epsilon + P(X_n\not\in I)\\
|Ef(X)-Ef_\epsilon(X)|\leq \epsilon + P(X\not\in I)<2\epsilon,\\
|Ef_\epsilon(X_n)-Ef_\epsilon(X)|\leq \sum_j|P(X_n\in I)-P(X\in I_j)||f(x_j)|\to 0.
$$

My problem is how to show how the first (and second) line arise. Mainly, I am a bit confused as to how the function $f_\epsilon$ should be treated. From my lecture notes I have the following:
$$
|Ef(X_n)-Ef_\epsilon(X_n)|\leq\int_I|f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n)|dP^{X_n}+\int_{I^c}|f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n)|dP^{X_n}
$$
where the first term is said to be $\leq \epsilon$ and the second $\leq P(X_n\in I^c)$. But how do I show this? From the construction of $f_\epsilon$ we know that $|f-f_\epsilon|<\epsilon$ on $I$, but does that really mean that the integral on $I$ is $\leq \epsilon$? Furthermore, am I right in saying that $f_\epsilon(X_n)$ in the second integral is $0$ since we're outside of $I$? If someone could help me with that first inequality I would be very grateful, as I think that would clarify a lot for me.

---

An attempt, please correct me if I'm wrong.

For the first part of the inequality, we know that $|f-f_\epsilon|<\epsilon$ on $I$. Hence, $\epsilon$ is the maximum distance and thus
$$
\int_I |f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n)|dP^{X_n}\leq \int_I\epsilon dP^{X_n}=\epsilon P(X_n\in I)\leq \epsilon.
$$
For the second part, the "$f$ takes values in $[-1, 1]$" comes into play, since
$$
\int_{I^c}|f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n)|dP^{X_n}=\int_{I^c}|f(X_n)|dP^{X_n}\leq P(X_n\in I^c)
$$
by a similar argument (i.e. |$f(X_n)$| is at most $1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first hesitation: we can take $f$ to have values in $[-1,1]$ because we are already assuming $f$ is bounded. Thus, if $M = \sup_x |f(x)|$, $f/M$ *does* take values in $[-1,1]$. The constant $M$ does no harm because $E[f(X)/M) = \frac{1}{M}E[f(X)]$, so the general case of values in $[-M,M]$ follows immediately from the $[-1,1]$ case.

For the  question about the inequality, if you agree that $|f - f_\epsilon| < \epsilon$ on $I$,
\begin{align*}
|Ef(X_n) - Ef_\epsilon(X_n)| &= \left|\int_\Omega f - f_\epsilon dP^{X_n}\right|\\
&=\left|\int_I f-f_\epsilon dP^{X_n} + \int_{I^c} f-f_\epsilon dP^{X_n}\right| \\
&\leq \int_I |f-f_\epsilon| dP^{X_n} + \int_{I^c} |f-f_\epsilon| dP^{X_n}.
\end{align*}

If we agree that $|f-f_\epsilon| < \epsilon$ on $I$, then it does really mean the integral over $I$ is less than $\epsilon$ because $I$ has measure at most $1$ (whereas you might be thinking of $I$ in terms of area in the Lebesgue sense...): 
$$\int_I |f-f_\epsilon| dP^{X_n} \leq \int_I \epsilon dP^{X_n} \leq \epsilon \int_\Omega dP^{X_n} = \epsilon\cdot 1.$$
For the second term, notice that on $I^c$, $f_\epsilon \equiv 0$. Then, by the comment about $f$ being bounded, 
$$\int_{I^c} |f-f_\epsilon| dP^{X_n} \leq \int_{I^c} dP^{X_n} = P(X_n \notin I).$$

Does this help?

Comment: This looks just like my attempt (just edited the question)! So it's very helpful, as it verifies my attempt (though yours is more nicely phrased...) :) Thanks! And your pointing out the boundedness assumption is helpful, as I was hesitant towards the $[-1, 1]$ part but that is, as you say, not much of an issue because of this.

Comment: @snarski: In the second to last mathematical line, where are you using the fact that the function f is bounded between 1 and -1? It seems to me that once you bring epsilon out of the integral and notice that I is a subset of Omega, you get the result. Where am I doing wrong?